# Count number of published posts by type

Tags: php, posts, wp-query, count, query-string

I have this code, but it shows the total number of posts published by post type 'code'.

```
<?php
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('code')->publish;
echo $count_posts;
?>
```

I have 2 post types: 'code' and 'shop'.
Post type code is "a child" for post type 'shop'.
Therefore I need to show the post count for the "child" post type 'code' for those attached to the "parrent" post type 'shop'.

UPDATE - SOLUTION (if any others are facing same problem) :

```
<?php
                            $result = $wpdb->get_results(
                                $wpdb->prepare(
                                    "SELECT COUNT(*) AS code_num FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta1 ON postmeta.post_id = postmeta1.post_id WHERE postmeta1.meta_key = 'code_expire' AND postmeta1.meta_value > %d AND postmeta.meta_key = 'code_shop_id' AND postmeta.meta_value = %s",
                                    current_time('timestamp'),
                                    $post->ID
                                )
                            );
                            $result = array_shift( $result );
                            echo '
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <span class="badge">'.$result->code_num.'</span>
                                    <a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ).'"> '.$post->post_title.' </a>
                                </li>';
    ?>
```

Big thanks to Ahmed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer the $wpdb direct queries you can use something like this:

```
global $wpdb;   
$count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'code' and post_status = 'publish'" );
echo $count;
```

In the sql query above change the `post_type` to whatever you like. This will return count of published posts under specific post type only.

If you want to query counts from multiple post types do this query:

```
global $wpdb;   
$count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type IN ( 'code', 'shop', 'post', 'etc' ) and post_status = 'publish'" );
echo $count;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, but i need to check for post type 'code' attached to post type 'shop' - It is 2 post types which are "attached" as parrent and child. A part of my theme uses this code to recieve the right count - but i cant get it to function in my other part of the theme files: "SELECT COUNT(*) AS code_num FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta1 ON postmeta.post_id = postmeta1.post_id WHERE postmeta1.meta_key = 'code_expire' AND postmeta1.meta_value > %d AND postmeta.meta_key = 'code_shop_id' AND postmeta.meta_value = %s",

Comment: The second query you suggested takes my "code posts" and pluses it with my 'shop posts'. instead i need the following: number of posts with post type 'code' which are attached to current post type 'shop' or "current page/url" if that makes sense? :-)

Comment: How are they attached? I mean is it a custom field which defines that this post is a child of that post type? If it's a custom field relationship, please give me it's key and the expected value.

Comment: Yes, like that. I am not sure what you mean by key and expected value. In the functioning query it uses: postmeta1.meta_key = 'code_expire' AND postmeta1.meta_value > %d AND postmeta.meta_key = 'code_shop_id' AND postmeta.meta_value = %s"

Comment: Can you paste the full functioning query in your edited question? Please.

Comment: Done. Thank you so much for your kindness!! I really appreciate your help! :-)

Comment: Have you tried to use the same query and change $popular_shop->ID with $post->ID or get_the_ID() (current page ID) if you are in single page ( I assume so) ? Basically the $popular_shop->ID is the post ID and they use that to find codes under specific shop ID in the query.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! <3 You just made my day for sure!! It works like a charm with  $post->ID ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0; 
$loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'code') );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  $count = $count + 1;
endwhile;

echo $count;
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan, but this gives me the same result as the code i pasted. The problem is that post type 'code' shows the total count of posts.
But i need the toal count for the "parrent" post type 'shop' for which the post type 'code' is posted in.

The structure is like:
Post type 'shop' = parrent "category",
Post type 'shop' = child "category" - so my 'code' post type is attached to 'shop' post type :-)

Comment: Change the post type from 'code' to 'shop'

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry i am so bad at explaining. i need the count for post type 'code' like you suggested. But i need only count of 'code' for those that are attached to post type 'shop' (like 'shop' is a parrent category, and 'code' is the child element) Does it make sense? :-)